# Getting started with rails? Must have gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm starting work on a project using Rails, but I'm waiting for the 3rd edition of the pragmatic rails book to come out before I purchase a book.

Anyway, my question is a bit more pointed than how do I get started...

What are some of the must have gems that everyone uses?

I need basic authentication, so I have the restful authentication gem, but beyond that, I don't know what I don't know. Is there a run down of this information somewhere? Some basic setup that 99% of the people start with when starting a new rails application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gems and plugins that I tend to use on most of my projects are:

- [Restful Authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master) -- For authentication
- [Will Paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master) -- For pagination
- [Attachment Fu](https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu/tree/master) -- For image and file attachments
- [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) -- For textile rendering
- [Capistrano](http://capify.org/) -- For deployment

Comment: I'd recommend Paperclip (http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree) instead of Attachment Fu - I've found it much simpler and less troublesome.

Comment: also authlogic (http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) pwns restful authentication

Answer (score 5):

For pagination, [will_paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master).

Answer (score 3):

This is very, very subjective because it all depends on what your application does! However, I've just had a look at the Gems I have installed and the one that absolutely does leap out as mandatory is [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/).

BTW Restful Authentication is a Rails plugin not a Gem.

Answer (score 3):

[HAML](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/docs/) is a must have. You'll never think of HTML in the same way again -- No more tag soup.

Comment: You trade tag soup for significant whitespace. Get that python out of my rails! BAH!

Comment: Yar, HAML is nasty, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Personally I like HAML's succinctness. HTML reduces to a nice outline, better showing what's going on in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The only gems you need are:

- Rails
- Rake

If you "gem install rails" you'll get everything you need for Rails.  You only need gems when you need them, so it's not worth worrying about before then.

EDIT:  Actually there are a couple more you'll probably need:

- mysql - or whatever Ruby database driver you need
- mongrel - you don't necessarily need this until production, but it's nice to use in dev/test too
- ZenTest - I use this mainly for "autotest" so that my tests run in a console window whenever my source files change

There could be many other gems that help you but we'd need more info from you to know if they're applicable, eg:

- Web scraping (hpricot)
- CSV (fastercsv)
- Amazon S3 support (aws-s3)
- Image manipulation (rmagick)
- Graphing (gruff) - I use this as a plugin
- Role-based security (role_requirement) - This one is a plugin too

Comment: But how do you know you need them, unless you know what's out there? :-)

Comment: I guess what I mean is, the OP didn't give us any indication of what he might need apart from authentication.  Without knowing what kind of app he's building, how can we recommend gems?

Comment: OK, I found a couple of others that I use that may help the OP, edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

- sudo gem install [haml](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/)
- sudo gem install [ZenTest](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/ZenTest/)
- [rspec on rails](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/wikis/home)

Comment: Install RVM and drop the `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

How can nobody have mentioned [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) yet? It's the best thing since `||=`

Comment: Link in answer seems dead - *"This site can’t be reached | andand.rubyforge.org took too long to respond."*.

Answer (score 0):

mini_magick instead of rmagick.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to keep an eye on: http://rubygems.org/ - you can see some interesting stats there re: most downloaded, most active, etc...

Also interesting and somewhat telling: https://github.com/languages/Ruby

Answer (score 0):

This is a old thread but I thought I'll refine the list with what I believe to be must have gems at this point in time:

- [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) or [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) - tools for BDD/testing
- [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) - fixture replacement
- [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) - simple pagination
- [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) - image uploading/attachment
- [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) - authorization
- [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) - authentication
- [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) - templating engine