# Which are the precious Rails RubyGems that Railers can't live without?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

**There are a lot of interesting gems beyond the classic Rails gem pack:** cucumber, formtastic, rspec, shoulda, coulda, webrat, selenium, will_paginate, authlogic, searchlogic, inherited resources ...

Let's make some effort to catalog the best Rails gems on SO.

I'm new to the Rails community and a little bit lost with so many options for resolving the issues.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116854/

Answer (score 2):

[Passenger](http://modrails.com/)!!

Answer (score 1):

- [NewRelic RPM](http://github.com/newrelic/rpm)
- [Hoptoad](http://www.hoptoadapp.com/)
- [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/)
- [Haml](http://github.com/nex3/haml/)

Answer (score 0):

Who could live without [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) and [hpricot](http://github.com/hpricot/hpricot)?

Also worth mentioning are two fine irb enhancers: [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) and [wirble](http://pablotron.org/software/wirble/)

Answer (score 0):

Clearance - http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance

Paperclip - http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

FactoryGirl - http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Sprockets - http://www.getsprockets.com/

Answer (score 0):

- RSpec - http://rspec.info/rails/
- Viget Deployment - http://github.com/vigetlabs/viget_deployment

Answer (score 0):

[jRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) of course.

Answer (score 0):

will_paginate,attachment_fu,rspec these are coool

Answer (score 0):

Devise for user authentication: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Prawn for PDF generation: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

ActiveScaffold for CRUD: https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold