# Must have ruby gems for every rails project (2011 edition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sup guys!

I've been searching around on StackOverflow and Google for lists of must-have gems that experienced people use for almost every project, but I've only been finding '08 and '09 editions.

What I'm looking for are gems that make features that will be used for almost every application (such as users signing up) much easier to implement.

I'm fairly new to rails myself but the following are some of my favorites:

- [Friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)
- [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Hopefully the experienced Rails users could show me a list of some useful Gems that I can use for my future projects as well. Sharing is caring!

*I know this isn't specifically a question but seeing as there's no active forums or community for rails whatsoever except this one, I've decided to add it here :)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with rails? Must have gems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116854/getting-started-with-rails-must-have-gems)

Comment: Rather than start a "2011" question, the Stack Overflow way is to add responses to an existing question to help keep the knowledge in one place. As soon as you add an answer or a comment to an unlocked question it will become new again, allowing others to see it as active. This is especially effective for community wiki questions.

Comment: That question has answers that are '08 and a couple of '10.
Besides, I needed a way to get the gems for 2011 together in one question  instead of "must have gems" which could mean any year :(

Comment: Maybe so. That doesn't mean old gems are worthless. If they are maintained then they are perfectly good. Rails is such an example, right? Having the older recommended gems in the same answer with newer ones also helps people with additional options when searching. Human nature is such that "old" things are not interesting, though they can be excellent choices still. The "new hotness" isn't necessarily better since it might not be vetted out and could have a lot of undiscovered bugs.

Comment: I want to add link to my gem https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db to explore DB and run SQL in browser

Answer (score 5):

yes, the trends are changing often. many of Rails developers use http://ruby-toolbox.com/ to see what's gems the actual and useful for today. choose what you need.

the most useful and popular in 2011 are the following:

**acts_as_paranoid** (300+ watchers) - ActiveRecord Soft Delete

**eventmachine** (1k+ watchers) - Asynchronous HTTP

**refinerycms** (1k+ watchers) - Content Management

**nokogiri** (1k+ watchers) - HTML parsing

**rails_admin** (2k+ watchers) - Rails Admin Interfaces

**devise** (4k+ watchers)- Rails Authentication

**cancan** (2k+ watchers) - Rails Authorization

**paperclip** (3k+ watchers) - Rails File Uploads

**friendly_id** (1k+ watchers) - Rails Permalinks & Slugs

**god** (800+ watchers) - Server Monitoring

**aasm** (1k+ watchers) - State Machines

**passenger** (1k+ watchers) - Web servers

And sure, [Github trend](https://github.com/languages/Ruby) are worth to see

Comment: Wow some really useful gems here! rails_admin seems really handy.

Answer (score 2):

[will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) is still a really useful gem. An easy and elegent way for handling pagination in your rails app.

Comment: Awesome! I've seen it mentioned a couple of times but I've never had to actually use it. I'll definitely keep it in mind though :)

Answer (score 1):

The most frequently used gems for me are:

[Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) - Super simple form builder to cut down on your view code, and makes reusing your form stylesheets super simple.  This is probably my favorite since I use it on every single project I start.

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) - Easy file attachment management for Rails ActiveRecord

DelayedJob - For asynchronously running background tasks.

ThinkingSphinx - Full-text search.

Passenger - Web server

RailsAdmin - Back end for administrators to view/update data.

WillPaginate - For easy pagination

I like these next couple, but they are somewhat controversial since it's mostly a developers preference:
haml - HTML Abstraction Markup Language - A Markup Haiku.  This is a nice alternative to erb templates.

sass - Sass makes CSS fun again. Great way to write css with variables, mixins, and some other nice features to cut down on how much css you actually have to write.

Full Disclosure I just finished writing this last Gem so I'm throwing it out there in case you need a simple contact form:

ContactUs - Rails 3+ Engine to add a simple contact form to your app.

Comment: Awesome list. The ContactUs gem seems extremely handy. Going to give it a try right now =)

Comment: Thanks I hope you like it.  If you run into any issues let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here a list of gems which weren't added to above answers.

**[searchlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/176-searchlogic)** - used for complex search.

**[prawn](http://www.rubyinside.com/prawn-ruby-pdf-library-987.html)** - for generating pdf

**[haml](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html)** - view engine

**[declarative_authorization](http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/09/delclarative-authorization/)** - for creating authorization rules for users.

Comment: Those seem very handy indeed! Thanks :)